# editing dynamically generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically generated tables the foot of the table contain some text fields when  click on save i want to add the value of text fields to the body of that table .
here is the table

```
<table border="1" class="entity_table">
 <tfoot>
   <tr>
     <td>
       <div class="pane1"></div>
       <div class="pane2">
        <input type="text" id="name"><br>
        <select id="data">
         <option value="1">int</option>
         <option value="2">tinyint</option>
        </select>
        <br><span id="save">save</span>
       </div>
     </td>
  </tr>
</tfoot>
<tbody class="table-body" id='myid'></tbody>
</table>
```

i did this but this is id specific ..i want to update that specific table on which it is clicked and edited .

```
var myName = document.getElementById("name");
    var data = document.getElementById("data");
    var Mtable = document.getElementById("myid");

    var rowCount = Mtable.rows.length;
    var mrow = Mtable.insertRow(rowCount);

    var mcell = mrow.insertCell(0);
    mcell.innerHTML = myName.value;
    var mcell1 = mrow.insertCell(1);
    mcell1.innerHTML = size.value;
```

i want to update each dynamically generated table with values that is entered in its table's foot section

Comment: this is pure js not jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below jQuery :

```
 $(function(){
      $('#save').click(function(){
         $(this).closest('table').find('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+$('#name').val()+' and '+$('#data').val()+'</td></tr>');
      }); 
  });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QA2Ec/25/)**

**EDIT** - to eliminate input and select box id dependency use below code :

```
$(function(){
    $('#save').click(function(){
     var name = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type=text]').val();
     var data =  $(this).closest('tr').find('select').val();                 
     $(this).closest('table').find('tbody').append('<tr><td>'+name+' and '+data+'</td></tr>');
    }); 
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QA2Ec/26/)**

Comment: but this is again id specific .. i want to select Tbody of that table in which it is clicked ??   i have more then one dynamic tables to update

Comment: please see the updated answer. but here I have used save button, input box and select id. If you want we can eliminate that also.

Comment: its adding the same value in all tables ... not that one which is added in that table

Comment: see this http://jsfiddle.net/QA2Ec/27/  I got two table and save button click event bind for first button only and this adds row to its table and not other table.

Comment: please check there should not be duplicate id for save button.

Comment: thanx for help ,,,but yes there are duplicate id in all tables what should i do for this ?? and its also repeating values in first table

Comment: use class instead of id like replace id="save" to class="save" and so on. and bind click event like $('.save')

Comment: yes its done ,but what about that repeating values in first created table .. if i generate two tables the first one  repeat the value two times i.e. add two rows with same value

Answer (score 0):

So if I understood this right, you dont want to use element's ID to select it.

You have some else options if you dont want to work with elements IDs:

1) You can add them some `data-` attribute, for example: `data-id`. And based on this you select your element like this:

`myElement.querySelector("[data-id='X']")` where `myElement` is some parent element of your tables and `X` is their ID which you generated before (lets say it will start from 0 and will increment with every next table).

2) If possible, **work with objects**. When you create your tables, you either create them with raw text with defining html elements or you create new elements with calling `createElement("table")` on `document` keyword. If second option is your option, you can save this elements to some array (myTables in this case) and then approach this elements in a standard way - lets say:

```
myTables[0].getElementsByTagName("input")
```

Hope it helps your issue. Hope I understood issue you were asking about.